# How Can I Make a div fall from top of page and bounce where I clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, animated

Here is my attempt so far http://thezoo.com/test/

At http://tooltipsy.com/samples.html his 7th example down the page labeled "More Extreme - how about falling from the sky"  makes a div fall from the top of the page and bounce above the clicked box.

I'm trying to get his code to work independently of his tooltip routines, to simply work with the basic jquery and UI library. His unique offering to the world is the falling from the top of the page part. I've tried a few onclick functions on a div or using a link trigger and replacing his 1st line with this:
 $('mydiv').click(function(){
 but no luck so far.  What am I missing?  I would like to use the falling from the sky routine with Qtip2 or ClueTip.

Here is how he did it:

```
$('.hastip').tooltipsy({
    offset: [-10, 0],
    show: function (e, $el) {
        $el.css({
            'left': parseInt($el[0].style.left.replace(/[a-z]/g, '')) - 50 + 'px',
            'opacity': '0.0',
            'display': 'block'
        }).animate({
            'left': parseInt($el[0].style.left.replace(/[a-z]/g, '')) + 50 + 'px',
            'opacity': '1.0'
        }, 300);
    },
    hide: function (e, $el) {
        $el.slideUp(100);
    }
});
```

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's jsfiddle with working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/4/

There's no fadeOut and other effects, only bounce from the top. I hope you'll get general idea how it works and adapt to you needs;

Comment: Wow - that is BAD TO THE BONE! Had you already used something like this or did you just whip it up from scratch?  If you gander at [http://thezoo.com/test/] TheZoo.com - do you think this can easily be combined with Qtip, Cluetip, or perhaps easiest of all - the basic Jquery tooltip I'm using there?

I like your LOTR quotes - Tolkien and C.S. Lewis rule ;-)

Comment: http://thezoo.com/test/bounce_1.htm

http://thezoo.com/test/bounce_2.htm

So I took your great code and added a fade to the bouncing LOTR div :-)

In bounce_1 - your bounce works fine - But the Jquery tooltips don't work with UI added. So I downloaded a custom Jquery UI without tabs and unchecked a few other things - but I cannot get both the tooltips and your bounce effect to work together.

My ultimate goal is to get the bounce effect working with Qtip, Cluetip and Jquery tooltips, but are these pipe dreams?

Comment: @user1192721, no, haven't used this one before just had some free time to write it. I doubt it'd be possible to add that functionality without rewriting bits an pieces of any of the tip plugins. Code above requires jQuery UI **Effects** library.

I could probably write a patch for a tip plugin, but which one?

Answer (score 2):

Just replacing his first line with your selector won't work because he is creating callbacks and passing them to his tooltipsy function.  Instead, what you'll want to do is execute the animation directly in the .click() function.  Something like this:

```
$('mydiv').click(function(){ 
    $(this).css({
        'left': parseInt($el[0].style.left.replace(/[a-z]/g, '')) - 50 + 'px',
        'opacity': '0.0',
        'display': 'block'
    }).animate({
        'left': parseInt($el[0].style.left.replace(/[a-z]/g, '')) + 50 + 'px',
        'opacity': '1.0'
    }, 300);
}
```

I didn't test this anywhere, so it probably won't work, but it should point you in the correct direction.  Also note that his "bouncyness" comes from the 'easeOutBounce' property.  This tells the animation framework to attempt to interpolate the position of the div based on his start and end parameters.  Normally there are quite a few defaults built in (like easeIn, easeOut, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes - that totally helps me understand the format - thank you! It seems quite different from the Jfiddle reply and more similar to the tooltipsy technique. Is one more advantageous than the other?

Comment: They are actually very similar.  The jfiddle reply computes the values based on the clicked area.  If you see the portion of his code where the animation happens, it's basically the same, just that he precomputes the values for the top.